# Wordpress paginate_links() set end_size to 0

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I created my own pagination in a website I'm working on. My paginations works fine but the page numbers' layout/UI breaks (specifically iPad) especially when it has 17 pages already.

I have set my `mid_size = 2` and `end_size = 0` but end_size still shows the first and last pages.

Currently, this is how my pagination looks:

< 1 ... 11 12 **13** 14 15 ... 18 >

It's not efficient to apply a CSS attribute of `display:none` to the dots coz it will look something like this:

< 1 11 12 **13** 14 15 18 >

I wanted it to appear something like this:

< 11 12 **13** 14 15 >

I want to maintain a `mid_size = 2`. If `end_size = 0` worked, it wouldn't be a problem.

I actually found this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237753/getting-paginate-links-end-size-to-display-none) but it doesn't work on my case, it returns an error. Or I may have applied it wrongly.

Current code:

```
<?php
        $big = 999999999;

        $html = paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'prev_text' => '<span></span>',
                'next_text' => '<span></span>',
                'mid_size' => 2,
                'end_size' => 0,
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $news_list->max_num_pages,
        ) );

        echo $html;

    ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: WP does allow you to set end_size as 0: `if ( $end_size < 1 ) { $end_size = 1; }`.